# How can I match an exact word in a string?

Tags: python, string

I have a string in which the word `local` occurs many times. I used the `find()` function to search for this word, but it will also find e.g. `locally`. How can I match `local` exactly?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

For this kind of thing, regexps are very useful :

```
import re

print(re.findall('\\blocal\\b', "Hello, locally local test local."))
// ['local', 'local']
```

\b means word boundary, basically. Can be space, punctuation, etc.

Edit for comment :

```
print(re.sub('\\blocal\\b', '*****', "Hello, LOCAL locally local test local.", flags=re.IGNORECASE))
// Hello, ***** locally ***** test *****.
```

You can remove flags=re.IGNORECASE if you don't want to ignore the case, obviously.

Comment: thanks its working.. but there is one more problem when i am trying to replace "Local" with another word it also replace "locally" like "*****ly".

Comment: It's the same thing, but you use re.sub instead of re.findall. I edited my post.

Comment: thank you .... its working..  i was trying it since three days.. you are really python guru.

Comment: This solution is not working all the time, if you search dynamically.
I did in this way....
var = "search element"
find = "\\b" + var + "\\b"
 result = re.findall(find, text)

Comment: Regular expression "\\b" search is more time consuming so if you would like to improve performance, you should do  "if needle in hay and len(re.findall("\\b" + needle + "\\b", hay)) > 0:"

Answer (score 14):

Below you can use simple function.

```
def find_word(text, search):

   result = re.findall('\\b'+search+'\\b', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
   if len(result)>0:
      return True
   else:
      return False
```

Using:

```
text = "Hello, LOCAL locally local test local."
search = "local"
if find_word(text, search):
  print "i Got it..."
else:
  print ":("
```

Answer (score 4):

```
line1 = "This guy is local"
line2 = "He lives locally"

if "local" in line1.split():
    print "Local in line1"
if "local" in line2.split():
    print "Local in line2"
```

Only line1 will match.

Answer (score 3):

You could use regular expressions to constrain the matches to occur at the word boundary, like this:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\blocal\b')
p.search("locally") # no match
p.search("local") # match
p.findall("rty local local k") # returns ['local', 'local']
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a regular expression search for \blocal\b

\b is a "word boundry" it can include beginnings of lines, ends of lines, punctuation, etc.

You can also search case insensitively.

Answer (score 1):

Look for ' local '? Notice that Python is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Using Pyparsing:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

def search_exact_word_in_string(phrase, text):

    rule = pp.ZeroOrMore(pp.Keyword(phrase))  # pp.Keyword() is case sensitive
    for t, s, e in rule.scanString(text):
      if t:
        return t
    return False

text = "Local locally locale"
search = "Local"
print(search_exact_word_in_string(search, text))
```

Which Yields:

`['Local']`

Answer (score 1):

```py
quote = "No good deed will go unrewarded"

location = quote.rfind("go")
print(location)
// use rfind()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for existence, try to think the other way...
and you can make something like this...

check for a pattern not equal to what you want exactly and if there's a match
then check if the result is equal to what you want.

```
    st1:str ='local!'
    st2:str =' locally!'
    match1 = re.search(r'local\w?',st1)
    match2 = re.search(r'local\w?',st2)
    print('yes' if match1 and match1.group()=='local' else 'no')
    print('yes' if match2 and match2.group()=='local' else 'no')
```