# Python: find exact match

Tags: python, regex

I would like to find words with the exact match using the find(). But it seams that find() returns strings with partial match as well.

Referring to previous posts in stackoverflow [String exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173787/string-exact-match) the following regex was used:

```
   import re

   print(re.findall('\\blocal\\b', "Hello, locally local test local."))
   // ['local', 'local']
```

The problem is that in my case "local." is different from "local"

How can I do that?

update:

What I need to do is to the replace the element which contains the work local.

```
  print("Hello, locally local test local#".replace('local','we'))
  // should result in 

  Hello, locally we test local#
```

Comment: `\b` matches between alphanumerics and non-alphanumeric letters. Therefore it matches between `l` and `.` - which definition of an "entire word" do you want to implement instead?

Comment: please state more clearly what you want and don't want to match. do you want to match all cases of "local" surrounded by non word characters or by white spaces?

Comment: Just out of curiosity what would be wrong with something like `'local' in "Hello, locally local test local."`

Comment: @johnthexiii The OP mentions `but it seams that find() returns strings with partial match` - so I guess `in` is out of the question

Comment: @JonClements, you're correct and my reading skill leave a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't make sense for a `findall` if all you're returning is a list of what you're looking for... For this use case, I wouldn't bother with an re, and just use:

```
'Hello, locally local test local.'.split().count('local')
```

---

Okay, an update related to:

> What I need to do is to the replace the element which contains the work local.

I'd go for something like:

```
re.sub(r'\blocal([\b\s])', r'we\1', s)
```