# python: replacing exact with minus sign

Tags: python, regex

Given the following string:

```
"-local locally local test local."
```

my objective is to replace the string "local" with "we" such that the result becomes

```
"-local locally we test local."
```

so far (with the help from the guys here at stackoverflow: [Python: find exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070566/python-find-exact-match)) I have been able to come up with the following regular expression:

```
variable='local'
re.sub(r'\b%s([\b\s])' %variable, r'we\1', "-local locally local test local.")
```

However I have two problems with this code:

1. The search goes through the minus sign and the output becomes:

   ```
   '-we locally we test local.'
   ```

   where it should have been

   ```
   '-local locally we test local.'
   ```
2. searching for a string starting with a minus sign such as "-local" fails the search

Comment: Why cant you just switch out `' local '` with `' we '`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
re.sub(r'(^|\s)%s($|\s)' % re.escape(variable), r'\1we\2', some_string)
```

The regex that was suggested in the other question is kind of odd, since `\b` in a character class means a backspace character.

Basically what you have now is a regex that searches for your target string with a word boundary at the beginning (going from a word character to a non-word character or vice versa), and a whitespace character at the end.

Since you don't want to match the final "local" since it is followed by a period, I don't think that word boundaries are the way to go here, instead you should look for whitespace or beginning/end of string, which is what the above regex does.

I also used `re.escape` on the variable, that way if you include a characters in your target string like `.` or `$` that usually have special meanings, they will be escaped and interpreted as literal characters.

Examples:

```
>>> s = "-local locally local test local."
>>> variable = 'local'
>>> re.sub(r'(^|\s)%s($|\s)' % re.escape(variable), r'\1we\2', s)
'-local locally we test local.'
>>> variable = '-local'
>>> re.sub(r'(^|\s)%s($|\s)' % re.escape(variable), r'\1we\2', s)
'we locally local test local.'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could separate the string into substrings using the spaces as the delimiter. Then check each string, replace if it matches what you are looking for, and recombine them.

Certainly not efficient though :)

Comment: This is efficient enough if the input data is just a few thousand lines, and more readable than regex.

Comment: In code: `" ".join("we" if p == "local" else p for p in s.split())`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/ local / we /g' filename
```

I don't do python, but the idea is just put a space before and after local in the pattern to find, and also include spaces in the replacement.

Comment: +1 but this fails for lines starting with local, you'd need another `sed 's/^local /we /g' filename` for that.

Comment: l4mpi: I realized my solution may have been overly specific.  I attempted to solve the question as presented because it was not made clear whether he wanted local at the beginning of a line to be replaced (especially because he did not replace the `local` in `local.`).  Hopefully, between the two of us, he finds what he is looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace all occurences of the word that are separeted by spaces, you could split the string and operate on the resulting list:

```
search = "local"
replace = "we"
s = "-local locally local test local."
result = ' '.join([x if not x == search else replace for x in s.split(" ")])
```

Comment: This works! but which is more efficient or the solution by F.J

Comment: @alandalusi The regular expression is more efficient, but I use code like this regularily if the input isn't huge; e.g. for a ~100k line csv file you probably won't notice the difference on a modern pc.