# exact string matching in python

Tags: python

```
sysList = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of System [PRIMARY|SECONDARY|]: ')).upper().strip()
p = re.compile(r'\\b'+sysList+'\\b')
nsysList = p.findall(" + sysList + ")
```

when I run this it asks for thr system and if I choose 'SECONDARY' this sysList variable will get execute in below command :

```
cmd = "mc-rpc -v " + dStr + " --with-fact serverName='/"+serverList+"/' --with-fact systemType='/"+nsysList+"/' -agent  mc_admin -action runcommand --arg command="+acommand+" > "
```

when above command runs it will execute in a server and through 'sysList' variable it searches a string called 'SECONDARY' in a file named xxx.yaml.
So I am getting more then one result which is matching 'Secondary' string in xxx.yaml file. like:

`SECONDARY
SECONDARY-HA`

but I want only SECONDARY should come instead of all matching pattern. Please help me.

Comment: you can refer to the accepted answer   here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173787/string-exact-match

Comment: @FullOfQuestions I have edited the code as per your given link. Can you please me know what wrong am I doing now

Comment: Did you find any change in the output or any error  after changing the code ???

Comment: @FullOfQuestions I am not getting any error nor any output.

Comment: replace your `\b` with `\s` to explicitly look for whitespace, then catpure `syslist` in a group with `()` so that `re.findall` will only return syslist and not the whitespace

Comment: @R Nar I doing like this now 
`p = re.compile(r'\s'+sysList+'\s')
nsysList = p.findall("+sysList+")`

But again go result. Please let me know where I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Change your second line to

```
p = re.compile(r'\b'+sysList+r'\b')
```

You don't want double `\\` in a raw string, because that's what they are for: making sure your escape sequences stay as they are.

Comment: Thanks, But I did the same but no success. Again getting no result.

Comment: I take it you are using Python2. So check your compiled regex stored in `p.pattern`. If it shows `'\\bSECONDARY\\b'`, it will work. Maybe the problem is in reading the yaml file's contents? How are you doing that? `open('xxx.yaml', 'r').read()`?