# How to match the exact pattern in a file

Tags: python

I have a file with below content

```
1191,agg.list,ShareCapitalHistory[CapitalAmount],CompanyElementDefinition
838983,atom.list,ShareCapitalHistory[CapitalAmount][*],CompanyElementDefinition
789,agg.list,CapitalAmount,CompanyElementDefinition
08f610,atom.list,CapitalAmount[*],CompanyElementDefinition
```

I am writing a program to filter all the lines that matches my key ignoring the brackets and stars. The key will the third column of the file which has agg.list. For example

`CapitalAmount` is a agg.list value and this will be the key for the search. And when I search with he above as key I should get CapitalAmount[*].

To achieve this I have the below program

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as myfile:
    for row in myfile:
        if (sys.argv[2] in row.replace('[', '').replace(']', '') and "[*]" in row):
            if row.split(',')[1] != 'agg.list':
                print row.split(',')[2]
```

I pass the second argument as `CapitalAmount` but what I get is shown below

```
CapitalAmount[*]
ShareCapitalHistory[CapitalAmount][*]
```

My program is checking if the key is available and prints all the lines that has the key in it. But what I want is to print only

```
CapitalAmount[*]
```

I heard about regsps and also found a relevant post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173787/string-exact-match).
But I am not sure how to use it in my program. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for this. If you do want to use a regex, both the square brackets and the asterisk need to be escaped to avoid using them as regex metacharacters. Using a raw string `r'\[\*\]'` avoids having Python interpreting the backslashes in the string before passing it to the regex engine.

Comment: But just split the row, extract the third field into a variable, remove the suffix, and compare and maybe print the resulting value in this variable.

Comment: My code works until it finds some line that has the same pattern. I looking for something that 'matches exactly the search string' and not 'contains the search string'

Comment: `var = row.split(',')[2].rstrip('[*]'); if var == 'CapitalAmount': print(var)` does exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as myfile:
    for row in myfile:
        split_line = row.split(',')
        list_name = split_line[1]
        dict_string = split_line[2]
        if "[" in dict_string:
            element = dict_string.split('[')[0]
        else:
            element = dict_string
        if list_name != 'agg.list' and sys.argv[2] in element:
            print("result of search for", sys.argv[2], ":", dict_string)
```