# python find exact word or phrase in string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following phrase:

```
phrase = 'My love for ict is strict'
```

I want to find specific phrase from a list.

```
phrase_list = ['My love', 'ict']
```

How can i find the exact phrases in phrase list in the phrase string?

I tried:

```
for p in phrase_list:
   pattern = re.compile(p)  
   result = pattern.findall(phrase)
   print(result)
```

The problem is that this prints:

```
['My love']
['ict','ict']
```

I would only want the occurrence of 'ict' that is an exact match:

```
['My love']
['ict']
```

How can I accomplish this for a large number of phrases?

Comment: do you mean you don't want to match the `ict` in `strict` ?

Comment: @TallChuck yes exactly!

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4173810/10484131)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\b` to match a word break (the boundary between a word and something that is not a word, such as punctuation or a space). Try changing `ict` to `\bict\b`