# Distinguishing Words with other Words within It

Tags: python, if-statement, embedding

so I'm trying to be able to detect only "astro" (case insensitive) in a sentence with other words that contain the word "astro" in it. For example:

```
message = 'Astro, the astronaut, studies astrology.'

if 'astro' in message:
    count = message.count('astro')
    print(count)
```

The output of this current code would be 3 because there are three words that contain that word in it, but I want the desired output to be 1; the first word. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Thats not python. Please post the code you are using. `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: How much Python do you know? For example, do you know regular expressions? Also correct your code to be runnable Python.

Comment: It's not something that i'm currently using it's a theoretical situation, the concept that i'm trying to explain is quite clear I believe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173787/string-exact-match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173787/string-exact-match)

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the message into separate words using `split`, and then use `startswith` to check if astro occurs at the start of the word.

Answer (score 0):

You need to massage the data a little bit.

```py
message = "Astro, the astronaut, studies astrology."
```

First, you need to get rid of everything that's not relevant to individual words.

```py
import string

valid = ' ' + string.ascii_lowercase
message = [char for char in message.lower() if char in valid]
message = ''.join(message)
```

Now, message looks a little different:

```py
>>> message
'astro the astronaut studies astrology'
```

Just re-split the message on spaces and count the occurrences!

```py
>>> message.split().count('astro')
1
```