# Python check if phrase is present in a sentence

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find if the words/string in the list are present in a given sentence.

```
sentence = 'The total number of cases in germany is equal to the inital cases from china'
listA = []
listA.append('equal to')
listA.append('good')
listA.append('case')


for item in listA:
    if item in sentence.lower().strip():
       print('success')
    else:
        print('Not Present')
```

I also tried with

```
if item in sentence.lower():
```

and

```
if item in sentence.lower().split():
```

But, this captures also the phrase `cases` or does not work for phrases

Comment: You have to split the `sentence` into a list of words before using `in`.

Comment: You can do one thing, attach spaces at front and end of the words in the list and then do the same what you've done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173787/string-exact-match)

Comment: Spaces aren't the way forward @strange.....unless you add a space to the sentence's start and end too. Word boundaries is what you want instead =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This thing checks for a substring, so any correct character sequence, no matter whether they are in the middle of word of not.

What you need is regex search - regex has a special character to mean "word boundary" - `\b`:

```
import re
for item in listA:
    if re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(item), sentence.lower().strip()):
        print('success')
    else:
        print('Not Present')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add spaces at front and end of the word and then check using the same code you've used.

```
for item in listA:
    if ' '+item+' ' in sentence.lower():
       print('success')
    else:
        print('Not Present')
```